# resize() with document or document.body.width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to use resize event with document width instead of window width.I need to use document width,not window.

```
 $(window).resize(function() {

    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
       $(document).getElementsByClass("razdel5").removeClass("d-none");
       $(document).getElementsByClass("fade-i").addClass("d-none");
    }
   else {
        $(document).getElementsByClass("razdel5").addClass("d-none");
        $(document).getElementsByClass("fade-i").removeClass("d-none"); 
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you just try with this:

```
$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
$(window).resize(function() {

    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
       $(".razdel5").addClass("d-none");
       $(".fade-i").removeClass("d-none");
    }
   else {
        $(".razdel5").removeClass("d-none");
        $(".fade-i").addClass("d-none"); 
   }
  });
```

Thanks all